# How to get location of the hand indoors

Tags: atmega328, gyroscope

I made a glove that tracks the positions of the fingers, but I don't know how to get the location of the hand relative to the person using them. Any suggestions? It should be quite accurate but I would really like to make even a rough prototype of it.

Ps. I'm using a Arduino Nano (atmega328p) to send and process the positions of the finger to a Java application through serial if you wanted to know.

Comment: Are you talking about a person and their **own** hand/fingers?

Comment: Yes. It reads the positions using a pressure sensors.

Comment: I think the easiest option is to measure the angles of the shoulder, elbow and wrist. Then use some math to calculate the position of the hand, with respect to the shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check the relative position is, first to define, what is the absolute position of a person, is it his other hand, his heart, his head, his foot?

When you defined the absolute position of the person, then you need to use a sensor at that absolute position that can measure the current position, e.g. GPS (if outside), but this is not accurate.

You also can use a gyroscope or device similar to what you use for the glove. When you initially keep them together you now the relative position (around 0.0). Than you can track movement differences of both the glove and the absolute position, send it to the glove (or vice versa) and calculate the difference. There might be calibration issues.

Another way is to use a camera and continueously check for a line of sight signal (IR, led), but this also can have issues (like distance measurement, what if there is no line of sight etc).

Comment: I tried using visual tracking but it might be quite impractical. Leap Motion has done some good work with hand tracking but I have no idea how they have accomplished it.

Comment: GPS would be way too for hand location. Ultrasonic sensing might work but I guess it might bounce from every object and create false readings.

Comment: I also don't have experience with this. I had a similar problem. Tracking the relativie position of a moving person and a static object, but even that is hard (line of sight, MPU6650 seems unreliable after half an hour, but maybe there are better gyroscopes. But you have two moving 'objects' (hand + absolute position). Also you can use one static object, and two relative positions (glove + absolute person) and send changes to the static object, but it will have also cons.

Comment: And ultrasonic does not work when line of sight is not present.